# Jquery TinyMCE Add/Edit Link - Cannot Paste in IE

Tags: jquery, tinymce, wysiwyg, text-editor, rich-text-editor

When using Jquery TinyMCE, select some text and try to add a hyperlink, Add/Edit Link tinymce popup window appears, but when I try to paste URL, I cannot get the right click "Paste" option enabled in IE, nor does Ctrl+V work.

This is only for IE browsers. I am able to paste in Chrome and FF.

This is how I have my tinymce configured.

```
:{
            theme: "advanced",
            mode : "specific_textareas",
            editor_selector: "richtext-editor",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location:"top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align:"left",
            theme_advanced_buttons1:"bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,fontsizeselect,forecolorpicker,|,link,unlink,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,cut,copy,paste,pastetext,|,undo,redo",
            theme_advanced_buttons2:"",
            theme_advanced_buttons3:"",
            theme_advanced_buttons4:"",
            plugins:"inlinepopups,paste",
            theme_advanced_path : false,
            inline_styles : true,
            paste_remove_styles: true,
            paste_retain_style_properties: "",
            paste_convert_headers_to_strong : true,
            invalid_elements : "img"
            //plugins:"advlink,iespell,inlinepopups,media,print,contextmenu,paste"
    }
```

Note:

Pasting in the editor itself works perfect in all the browsers. I have also tried enabling the contextmenu but no luck.

Also I double checked that the url I wanted to paste is indeed copied to the clipboard

Thanks.

Comment: +1 good question. i strongly suggest everyone not to use the jquery tinymce build because it is slow and a source of trouble

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue.

It was the "inlinepopups" plugin that was disabling the clipboard cut/copy/paste on the popup.

Removing inlinepopups did the trick and now pasting url on Add/Edit Link popup works in all the browsers.

One thing to note: It's recommended to disable this plugin only for IE, because it is a useful plugin, all what this plugin does is, it helps treat these dialog popups as inline popups so that one does not run into the issues where the site or the browser has a popup blocker.

Thanks

--

HRN